# Delphi TCriticalSection Acquire vs Enter - what is the difference?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, critical-section

I am updating Delphi (Delphi 2009) code which uses exclusively `TCriticalSection.Acquire/Release` pairs, not `Enter/Release or Leave` pairs. My question is - what is the difference between `Acquire` and `Enter`?

Delphi documentation is quite obscure - it even tries to say, that there is no difference:

http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/!!MEMBERTYPE_Methods_SyncObjs_TCriticalSection.html

> Acquire: Binds the critical section to the calling thread. Call
> Acquire to block all other threads from acquiring this critical
> section until the Release or Leave method is called. Acquire does the
> same thing as the Enter method.
>
> Enter: Blocks other threads when the calling thread enters a
> thread-sensitive section. Call Enter to block all other threads from
> entering code protected by this critical section until the Leave or
> Release method is called. Enter calls the Acquire method to bind the
> critical section to the calling thread.

I would like to have the method `TryAcquire`, but there is no such method, so - I am considering to replace all my calls to `Acquire` with `TryEnter... Sleep...` loop, that is bounded by the number of TryEnter calling efforts. But to be sure what will hapen, I should know the distinction between `Acquire` and `Enter`? What is this distinction? Why two different methods?

Comment: `Enter` is just an alias for `Acquire` and `Acquire` is inherited name from `TSynchroObject` with overriden implementation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `TCriticalSection` there is no difference. `Enter` is implemented as a call to `Acquire`. Likewise for `Leave` which is implemented as a call to `Release`.

The `TryEnter` method was added after Delphi 2009. But it's just a simple wrapper around the Windows API call `TryEnterCriticalSection`. You can call that function directly yourself. You could, for example, use a class helper to introduce `TryEnter` into the scope of `TCriticalSection`.